# How to Load data from CSV into separate Hadoop HDFS directories based on fields

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a CSV of data and I need to load it into HDFS directories based on a certain field (year). I am planning to use Java. I have looked at using BufferedReader however I am having trouble implementing it. Would this be the optimal thing to use for this task or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Spark to read the CSV into a dataframe.

use `partitionBy("year")` during writing to HDFS, and it'll create sub-folders under the path starting with `year=` for each unique value.

Comment: Would there be a way to do this without using spark?

Comment: Sure. Flink, Beam, Hive or Pig can all accomplish the same thing. Java's builtin BufferedReader cannot

Comment: could you give me tips on how to do this via hive? 

the date column is : yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: I suggest creating a new post specifically asking for Hive, but the short answer is that you use a CTAS query with a PARTITION BY clause. Date format doesn't matter